# Adding Activity/Loading Indicator at the Bottom of UCollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2, activity-indicator

I am wondering what is the best approach to add an Activity Indicator to the bottom of the UICollectionView.

I would like to able to show and display this cell, and I am wondering how should I do this.

I have searched SO and I have found people suggesting adding a new cell to the last row. But I would like to have the instance of the activity indicator so that I can turn it on or off.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new cell to the last row of your collection view and create a custom UICollectionViewCell class for that cell where you can enter the logic of your cell e.g.:

```
import UIKit

class LoadingCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func stopLoading() {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

You can then call the function stopLoading() in your ViewController when you want the activity indicator to stop.